# How can I link a user with a shopping cart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, shopping-cart

My app has both users and a shopping cart.

Theres currently no link between users and shopping carts.

At the moment regardless of if a user is logged in or not there is only one shopping cart available, the current_cart is created when a product is added and an order_transaction is created when the cart is paid for (success or fail). If successful, a new cart will be created the next time a product is added to the cart.

How can I link a cart with a user, so each user has a new cart created for them when adding a product?

**application_controller**

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def current_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil if @current_cart.purchased_at
    end
    if session[:cart_id].nil?
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
    end
    @current_cart
  end
```

**routes**

```
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"

  get "cart" => "carts#show", :as => "current_cart"

  resources :orders
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts    
  resources :products
  resources :order_transactions

  resources :sessions
  resources :users
```

**line_items_controller**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = LineItem.create!(:cart => current_cart, :product => @product, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => @product.price)
    flash[:notice] = "Added #{@product.name} to cart."
    redirect_to current_cart_url
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to **make the user have a cart**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cart

  def current_cart
    if self.cart.empty?
      self.cart.create!
    end
    self.cart
  end
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def add_line_item(item)
    etc...
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def current_cart
    current_user.current_cart if current_user.present?
  end
end
```

I would recommend this. That way, you only have **ONE** thing to keep track of in session. You should also try to move as much of the "business logic" DOWN to the model tier, to make it easier to test.